# Is the user required to be logged in to Google Play if I am using Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

Is the user required to be logged in to Google Play if I am using Google Play Services?

Specifically, I am using LocationClient and LocationRequest APIs.

Comment: I don't think so unless you are requesting google play function that requires them to access, however I think you have to enable those user rights to access those apis.

Comment: Good question! I don't think so. They need play services installed which means they've probably been signed into Google Play at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

> You are not required to be login to Google Play services in the device
>
> Just Google Play Services is required to be installed in the device
>   which is running the apk

Answer (score 1):

No, [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) (as `LocationClient` no longer exists as of Google Play services 6.5) does not require the user to login. In fact, like much of Google Play services, they don't even require a Google account be on the device - only that the Google Play Store and Google Play services is installed.